# Windows Server 2019 KB4524244 Error 0x800f0922

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2019

Getting this error (0x800f0922) when installing update KB4524244. Can't find any specifics yet. Just did a sfc /scannow and got 100% verified so not sure where to check on why it is failing.

Error log from the CBS.log

```
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Error                 CBS    Exec: An error occurred while committing the transaction, the transaction has been rolled back. [HRESULT = 0x800f0922 - CBS_E_INSTALLERS_FAILED]
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Perf: InstallUninstallChain complete.
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CSI    0000005b@2020/2/21:14:19:27.622 CSI Transaction @0x200fbe0bf80 destroyed
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Failed to execute execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x800f0922 - CBS_E_INSTALLERS_FAILED]
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Error                 CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x800f0922 - CBS_E_INSTALLERS_FAILED]
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    WER: Generating failure report for package: Package_for_KB4524244~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4, status: 0x800f0922, failure source: Execute, start state: Partially Installed, target state: Installed, client id: WindowsUpdateAgent
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Not able to query DisableWerReporting flag.  Assuming not set... [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Enumerating Foundation package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17763.1, this could be slow
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20200221141912.log to WER report.
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20200221125608.log to WER report.
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20200220191438.log to WER report.
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20200220144214.log to WER report.
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20200220022301.log to WER report.
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Not able to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml to WER report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2020-02-21 09:19:27, Info                  CBS    Not able to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml.bad to WER report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because KB4524244 has been rescinded by Microsoft.

Comment: Great just found this out. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update was rescinded by Microsoft. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1909#392msgdesc